# How to get multiple URL redirection details?

Tags: redirection, url, url-shortening

I have some affiliated links, by clicking the link it redirects to another link. It might be up to three levels.

```
abc.com/?affid=12/www.xyx.com -->
xyz.com?ref=23 -->
and finally shopsomething.com
```

As above example links are redirecting, are there any tools available so can get where this URL will redirect to know the path/link?

In normal conditions it happens so fast that I can't copy-paste links.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to automate this process, you can try [LongUrl](http://longurl.org/). It will give a detailed preview of the redirections.

Comment: Thanks but, its only available for short url services. like tinyurl , bytly

Comment: I tested this service with non shortener services, and it worked.

However, I just did some more tests, and it seems to stop working from 50 characters...